# How to create authentication API in WSO2 IS

Tags: authentication, soap, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to deploy a SOAP based authentication API in WSO2 Identity Server.

I want to deploy an Identity Provider based on JDBC (MySQL) User Store and expose it in a Service Provider to authenticate (user, password) and register users.

The User Store is already configured by MySQL. But, I don't find a clear documentation/tutorial/example to do this.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my own question:

http://soasecurity.org/2013/12/10/user-role-management-with-wso2-identity-server-apis/

Identity Server has an API to management user role, allowing authenticate, addUser, etc.